# How to limit ASoC configuration parameters?

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, alsa

I wrote a custom codec driver and an ASoC sound card that uses it. The codec driver is limited to the rate of `SNDRV_PCM_RATE_96000` and format `SNDRV_PCM_FMTBIT_S24_LE` in its `snd_soc_dai_driver`, however when running the `speaker-test` utility, ANY configuration gets accepted - shouldn't anything except for 24bit 96kHz be rejected?

```c
static struct snd_soc_dai_driver custom_dai = {
    .name = "custom-hifi",
    .playback = {
        .stream_name = "Custom Playback",
        .channels_min = 2,
        .channels_max = 2,
        .rates = SNDRV_PCM_RATE_96000,
        .formats = SNDRV_PCM_FMTBIT_S24_LE // I'm not sure MSB or LSB? 
    },
    .capture = {
        .stream_name = "Custom Capture",
        .channels_min = 2,
        .channels_max = 2,
        .rates = SNDRV_PCM_RATE_96000,
        .formats = SNDRV_PCM_FMTBIT_S24_LE // I'm not sure MSB or LSB? 
    },
};
```

The codec isn't connected to my RPi, maybe that's why everything is accepted? My understanding is that if the HAT is attached doesn't matter in this case, it's the code that defines the behavior of the sound card and in this case the behavior does not seem to follow the code.

I did test this with `hifiberry-dac` (again, not physically attached, just the dt-overlay enabled) which uses `PCM5102a` codec with a very similar driver to my custom codec driver. The behavior is the same, ANY configuration gets accepted. Is there a specific reason behind this? Even `speaker-test -D sysdefault:CARD=sndrpihifiberry -c 99 -r 700000 -F S24_3BE` is accepted and that can't work with `PCM5102a`!

Comment: Have you tried to ask in alsa-devel@ mailing list?

Comment: Not yet, maybe I should give it a go.